# SeekBar - move the thumb on the seekBar when the thumb is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I want to implement an Android SeekBar and I want to allow to users only the swiping, not taping i.e. I want to allow move the thumb on the seekBar when the thumb is pressed. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: It only swipes anyway. Tapping as in you don't want it to change when just pressed like a button?

Comment: I want to allow move the thumb on the seekBar when the thumb is pressed.

Comment: You can implement `OnTouchListener` method for seekbar.

Comment: But that what it does anyways. [Go through this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/seekbar/android-seekbar-example/)

Comment: It's not true, because when the thumb is in the centre of the seekbar, and I tap on the end of the seekBar the Thumb jumps to the end....

Comment: It is possible, little tricky though. Make a custom class that extends seekbar. Overwrite the `ontouchevent()`, only process it if the event x&y are within the thumb bounds. You can get the thumb drawable details from the overwriting the `setThumb()` method. Then you just need to work out the position of the thumb drawable based on the progress of the bar and the size of the view.

Comment: it's really tricky, but I will try it.